# What is the difference between default constructed object return and empty braces return in C++?

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

In the following code:

```
#include <memory>

struct A;

std::unique_ptr<A> ok() { return {}; }

std::unique_ptr<A> error() { return std::unique_ptr<A>{}; }
```

Clang++ compiles fine `ok()` function and rejects `error()` function with the message:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/memory:76:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-11.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11.1.0/../../../../include/c++/11.1.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:83:16: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'A'
        static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/M8qofYbzn

If there any real difference between default constructed object return and empty braces return in C++ (both in general, and in this particular case)?

Comment: I think this could be a clang bug, GCC and MSVC don't compile either function

Comment: Can someone explain what the clang's optimized assembly of `ok` does? `mov     rax, rdi; mov     qword ptr [rdi], 0; ret` I suspect RVO but not sure.

Comment: @Quimby In `rdi`, caller passes into `ok` an address of the storage for the returned object. `ok` function initializes this object by a default constructor, which just sets its member pointer into `nullptr`. This corresponds with setting its binary representation to zero bytes by the `mov` instruction. Finally, the address of the object is passed back in `rax`.

Comment: More minimal example of the same issue: https://godbolt.org/z/PWrvvGEbh.

Comment: @DanielLangr Thank you for the explanation, I am terrible at assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither should compile.

The destructor for the result object [is always potentially invoked](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return#3). In the case of `unique_ptr` that requires `A` to be complete.